# how to load model from one server to different client application for provide database access stuff in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I try to provide my model files in server that can be shared to the different clients application.

Consider the following Theoretical image,

[provide model files as cdn link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQfDa.jpg)

I don't know how to achieve this.

Please give suggestion to solve my problem?

Comment: what do you want ultimately ?and why you would want to share model?

Comment: I want to hold my model files in one server which those are dynamically loaded to  another server for the database work stuff.

for example, cdn files loading into our project.

Comment: How you're fetching models php files from other server ? As a php file and saving it in temp directory ?

Comment: I am not looking in that way and also don't like to store the model in temp directory. I want to access the model like the cdn link.

Comment: It's not possible in any way

Comment: Even if you make that happen, it will be public so your code no more secure from public access, unless you have some kind of authentication

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're fetching models from other server.

If you're fetching as a files with `php` extension and saving temporarily in your server, then you have to give path of that directory in `/system/core/Loader.php` file, where it looks for models in directory to load.

See screenshot below:

[image]