# How to access database of different servers from one server?

Tags: database, codeigniter, server, codeigniter-restserver

I would like to  wrap all database related process stuff in models and host it in an server(Master).

Then, Host the App in another server. The App consist only controller and view files. CRUD operation done with the help of Master server and store data in client server.

Consider the following Theoretical image,

[Access different server database from Master Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH11q.jpg)

Is it possible?

How to achieve this process?

Give me some suggestion please?

Comment: How is this question different from the [question you asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954911/how-to-load-model-from-one-server-to-different-client-application-for-provide-da)?

Comment: @DFriend , Now check the question once again and then you will understand.    [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954911/how-to-load-model-from-one-server-to-different-client-application-for-provide-da)